# Why my angularjs ng-model value got undefined?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

Suppose I have a text box and with ng-model. I got the value of textbox undefined.if i give the ng-model name a object type then it's working fine.

html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="test()">
```

controller

```
$scope.test=function()
{
  var val=$scope.search;
  alert(val);
}
```

if we give value in text box it always alert undefined.
if we give the value outside of the function like this

```
$scope.search=33;
$scope.test=function()
{
      var val=$scope.search;
      alert(val);
 }
```

it shows the value in text box

Now I change the scenario

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.text" ng-change="test()">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.search={'text':''};
$scope.test=function()
{
  var val=$scope.search.text;
  alert(val);
}
```

Now I got the value of the text box.What is the problem in the first scenario.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is most probably that your input is inside an ng-if, ng-repeat, or another directive that defines its own child scope. So the value is stored in this child scp, instead of being stored in the controller scope. You should always use an object to store your model (and initialize the object in the controller)..

Comment: Your first bit of code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/sm20exfe/

Comment: I know first bit code work fine in a simple test environment. But in my large product i have to work on a small part and there it is not running.But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect `$scope.search`to be an object, then what you have, without having to initialize `$scope.search=33;` or `$scope.search={'text':''};` should work fine.

If you want `$scope.search` to be a string, then you still do not need to initialize, but will need to change the `ng-model` binding to `ng-model="search"` instead of `ng-model="search.text"`.

Try the following:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.testSearchText=function()
  {
    var val=$scope.searchText;
    alert(JSON.stringify(val));
  };

  $scope.testSearchObject=function()
  {
    var val=$scope.searchObj;
    alert(JSON.stringify(val));
  };
}]);

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="SearchText">Search Text</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="testSearchText()">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="SearchText">Search Object</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchObj.text" ng-change="testSearchObject()">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or look at the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/LOMlFZsKuPcnJZhtcSuQ?p=preview